# Range of values for a cell in Numbers?

Tags: numbers

Is it possible to have a range of values for a cell in Numbers? E.g. for financial calculations involving income and costs, is it possible to have a "vague" value like `$ 1,000 - 3,000`, and base a calculation in another cell on it like `=SUM(A1:A3)`, and that sum will output as a calculated range like `$ 10,000 - 40,000`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in one cell, but in two adjacent cells that is easy for both input pair and output pair.

However, the two outputs could be shown in one cell by using the separate calculations joined by concatenate.

Comment: Too bad, thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: @deceze well you could put both numbers into one cell and then use left() and right() with find() to separate them for calculations but that just seems to add levels of complexity.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping for some sort of range-value type to make things *easier*, not complicate it more. ;)